# Discord.py on_member_join() sending a message into a specific channel

Tags: python, discord.py

So i was writing a simple discord bot where when an user join it would simply send a message in the main channel saying something like hello user. Everything was working, at first i printed that a user joined on the console and everything worked. Then i tried to do it in a channel by using `channel = client.get_channel("my channel here") await channel.send("Hello")` but it's not working as intended. So i was wondering if there was a way to do this.

(Btw this is my first stackoverflow question, so if there's anything i did wrong pls let me know)

Here is the Full code:

````
from discord.ext import commands


intents = discord.Intents()
intents.members = True

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents = intents)


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("The bot logged on")
    print("-----------------")

@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    print("Somebody joined")
    channel = client.get_channel(my channel here)
    await channel.send("Hello")


client.run("MY token") 

And here is the error:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'```
````

Comment: It can't find the channel. Remember, IDs are ints not strings. In your example, you have a string passed to `get_channel`.

Comment: I tried doing that but i still get the same error.

Comment: Try using `fetch_channel` instead of `get_channel`

Comment: TypeError: can't send non-None value to a just-started coroutine, now i get this error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `await fetch`, because the cache might not have the channel in there when the member joins. Your coroutine error comes from not `await`ing it. (An unexecuted coroutine object gets assigned to `channel`, and then you get an error when it tries to call that because it was "already called".)

```py
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    print("Somebody joined")
    channel = await client.fetch_channel(123456789)
    await channel.send("Hello")
```